# Determine Gaussian quadrature formula

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, quadrature

I want to calculate the integral $$\int_0^1\frac{1}{x+3}\, dx$$ with the Gaussian quadrature formula that integrates exactly all polynomials of degree $6$.

First of all do we have to transform the intervall of the integral, i.e. to shift it from $[0,1]$ to $[-1,1]$, or not?

Then I thought that it holds the following:

The gaussian quadrature integrates exactly polynomials $\Phi (x)$ with maximum degree $2n-1$. $2n-1$ is an odd degree but we have in this case the degree $6$, which is even.

What do we have to do in this case? Or is the way I am thinking wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your first question is yes, you have to transfer the interval to $[-1,1]$ in order to apply the Gaussian Quadrature. The transformation $x=\frac {t+1}{2}$ would do the trick.

For your second question you need to consider $n=4$ so you get $2n-1=7$ which covers the polynomials of degree 7 as well as polynomials of degree 6. Clearly $n=3$ is not sufficient because you get $2n-1=5$

Comment: So can we determine the Gaussian quadrature formula only at $[-1,1]$ ? Which is the weight function in this case?

Comment: The coefficients $c_i$ and the nodes $t_i$ are listed in numerical texts. Once you made the transformation to $t$ you apply the quadrature formula to approximate the integral.

Comment: But for the calculations of $c_i$ and $t_i$ do we not need the weight function?

Comment: You need $ f(t_i)$ and $c_i$ to find the quadrature.

Comment: I got stuck right now. In general we have an integral $\int_{-1}^1f(x)\cdot w(x)\, dx$, or not If we have $w(x)=1$ do we consider the Legendre polynomials?

Comment: If so because of what we said above do we want to use 4 nodes? Or am I thinking completely wrong?

Comment: The answer is $c_1 f(t_1)+c_2 f(t_2)+c_3 f(t_3) +c_4f(t_4)$

Comment: Ok! But which formulas do we use for the $c_i$ and $t_i$ ?

Comment: These are standard values which you can find in any numerical analysis text.